# what is the syntax i need for my worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

> =IFERROR(INDEX(Table2,SMALL(IF(Table2[Off The
> Road]="No",ROW(Table2)-4),ROW(43:43)),5),"")

That's the formula i'm currently using. But i want it to only work if 2 criteria are met

```
Table2[Off The Road]="No" and Table2[Spare]="No"
```

I've tried using the following formula, but it keeps returning a #Spill error

> =IFERROR(INDEX(Table2,SMALL(IF(and(Table2[Off The Road]="No",Table2[Spare]="No"),ROW(Table2)-4),ROW(43:43)),5),"")

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use FILTER() instead: `=FILTER(CHOOSECOL(Table2[#Data],5),(Table2[Off The Road]="No")*(Table2[Spare]="No"),"")`  It will spill all those that match, no need to drag the formula.

Comment: If what Scott Craner commented is not what you're after, it's better to share some sample data along with expected result

Comment: I am assuming `Table2[Off The Road]` is a column of multiple values, and thus `Table2[Off The Road]="No"` will be an array of true and false values.  ANDing two arrays together will not produce a result array.  The right approach would be a binary and operation using the multiplication operator instead:  `(Table2[Off The Road]="No")*(Table2[Spare]="No")`  I frankly don't understand the rest of the logic, so I can't comment further, I just don't think AND() is going to work for your case.

Comment: Thanks everyone, i kinda found a workaround to my problem. Your help was much appreciated